# Rrd4j persistence

Tags: rrd

I am using rrd4j to do what rrd4j does, and it works great. However, if I shut down my app and start it back up again, the data from the previous session will be gone.

I am using a normal file backend, like so:

```
RrdDef rrdDef = new RrdDef( "/path/to/my/file", 3000 );
```

Is there a setting or something I need to trigger to make rrd4j load the data from the previous session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you should use RrdDb("/path/to/my/file") instead. From Javadocs:

> RrdDb(java.lang.String path): Constructor used to open already
>   existing RRD in R/W mode, with a
>   default storage (backend) type (file
>   on the disk).

And also:

> RrdDb(RrdDef rrdDef):
>   Constructor used to create new RRD object from the definition.